# Unsupported operating system for MySQL Workbench - windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7, operating-system, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL in my python 2.7 project. 
I have created a database and tables on a windows 7 professional operating system (64-bit).

I want to see the data that is stored in the database's tables, using MySQL Workbench. The problem is I am getting the following message:

[image]

What should I do to solve this problem?

I know there is a MySQL archive from which I can download earlier versions of the workbench, but I don't know what version is suitable for my operating system. Does anybody know?

link to the archive - 
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade Windows to Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install older version from mysql workbench download arechives https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ and choose version `8.0.12`

Install older version from mysql community edition download archives
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/ and choose version `8.0.11` download the `Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive`

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is not a supported platform. See the platform list on the MySQL site: https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html.

Comment: And what about the MySQL Server? Does it support Windows 7?

Comment: No, Win 7 is EOL'ed already. The MySQL Server also supports Windows 10 only (https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html) + the 3 last Windows Server versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully using MySQL Workbench version 8.0.12 on Windows 7.

(Apparently this was the latest supported version and it doesn't have the compatibility warning.)

Answer (score 0):

Please download a lower version of Mysql Workbench(in archives section on download page). This solved my problem.